# undefined local variable or method `welcome_goodbye_path' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, error-handling

I am a beginner in rails and trying to learn using "Agile Web Development using Rails".I wanted to create a link to a webpage.This is my code:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
<p>
It is now <%= Time.now %>
</p>
<p>
Time to say
<%= link_to "Goodbye", welcome_goodbye_path %>!
</p>
```

But this gives error...

```
undefined local variable or method `welcome_goodbye_path'
```

What am I doing wrong ?
This is the code of my welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def goodbye
  end
end
```

This is the result of rake routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
welcome_index GET    /welcome(.:format)           welcome#index
              POST   /welcome(.:format)           welcome#create
  new_welcome GET    /welcome/new(.:format)       welcome#new
 edit_welcome GET    /welcome/:id/edit(.:format)  welcome#edit
      welcome GET    /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#show
              PATCH  /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#update
              PUT    /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#update
              DELETE /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#destroy
         root GET    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to show `config/routes.rb`.  You need something in there like:

```
get 'goodbye', to: 'welcome#goodbye', as: 'welcome_goodbye'
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!! It solved my problem ...If you could provide me some info so as to why I need to do this..That would be great!!

Comment: Read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and you'll know everything you need to know. (read all those guides.. tbh they're better than most of the books if you ask me)